# Как правильно обновлять запись в бд?

Tags: веб-программирование, rest, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Есть модель юзера, предполагается, что по юзернейму можно обновить запись в бд а именно - сразу несколько полей. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что возникает дублирование кода и попробывал решить ее через использование словарей, но user_db.username хранит только само значение,  а не ссылку.
Пробывал так же через user_db.**dict**, но тут тоже, изменения не регистрируются.
Как это правильно сделать?

```
  @router.put('/user/update')
    def update_user(username: Annotated[str, Body()], new_user: Annotated[UserUpdate, Body()],
                    db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
        user_db = db.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
        if not user_db:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='user with username not found')
        user_dict = {
            'username': user_db.username,
            'password': user_db.password,
            'firstname': user_db.firstname,
            'lastname': user_db.lastname,
        }
        new_user_dict = new_user.dict()
        for key in new_user_dict.keys():
            if new_user_dict[key]:
                user_dict[key] = new_user_dict[key]
        try:
            db.add(user_db)
            db.commit()
        except:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='user with username already registered')
    
        return 'yes'
```

Есть аналогичный код, где ссылки отрабатывают замечательно:

```
def filter_atm(atm_filter: AtmFilter, db: Session):
    filters_dict = {'blind': Atm.blind,
                    'is_all_day': Atm.is_all_day,
                    'wheelchair': Atm.wheelchair,
                    'nfc_for_bank_cards': Atm.nfc_for_bank_cards,
                    'qr_read': Atm.qr_read,
                    'supports_usd': Atm.supports_usd,
                    'supports_eur': Atm.supports_eur,
                    'supports_rub': Atm.supports_rub,
                    'supports_charge_rub': Atm.supports_charge_rub,
                    }
    current_filters = atm_filter.dict()
    atms = db.query(Atm)
    for key in current_filters:
        if current_filters[key]:
            atms = atms.filter(filters_dict[key] == 1)
    return atms.all()
```

Но когда работаю с конкретной записью в БД, то эта магия перестает действовать.